# Location based recommendation framework for Python

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to implement a location-based recommendation service in Python (as a Django app), where based on the user's supplied location (town, city, country), I can retrieve records for other users located within 50 miles of the user. Are there existing frameworks available to do this?

Comment: what about geoIP: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean by framework.  Getting user location is one task, getting recommendations another.  Getting the location will be fairly easy (HTML5, IP lookup, etc.).  The recommendation system is a more personal choice.  I recommend reading [this article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/Amazon-Recommendations.pdf) about Amazon, then checking out the tutorial [here](http://www.slideshare.net/100k100k/recommendations-with-hadoop-streaming-and-python?utm_source=Python+Weekly+Newsletter&utm_campaign=000b7d6a9b-Python_Weekly_Issue_36_May_24_2012&utm_medium=email) and the github project [here](https://github.com/orf/MovieFinder?utm_source=Python+Weekly+Newsletter&utm_campaign=9dc22cf663-Python_Weekly_Issue_34_May_10_2012&utm_medium=email).